# undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to complete a cart part in a site. The first time i add items into the cart it is ok, but the second time with the same items i would get a error:

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #19):

current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)  
if current_item  
  current_item.quantity += 1  
else  
  current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)  
end
```

What is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantity field is probably null in the database. Change the infringing line to something like:

```
current_item.quantity = current_item.quantity.to_i + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`nil.to_i` returns `0`

So use `current_item.quantity = current_item.quantity.to_i + 1`

Comment: current_item.quantity.to_i += 1 will return error if quantity value is nil.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `current_item.quantity` is `nil`.

Try to set default value with

```
...
if current_item
  current_item.quantity ||= 1 # sets to 1 if nil
  current_item.quantity += 1  
else
...
```

If you store `quantity` in database, then add to your migration like `null: false, default: 1`

Hope it helps.